# syntax error while insert into a table

Tags: sql, vb.net, postgresql

my table

```
    CREATE TABLE tbl_region
(
  id integer,
  "desc" character varying(100)
)
```

and the following is the code that i wrote in `VB.NET` to `INSERT` into the above mentioned table

```
 Using conn As New NpgsqlConnection("Server=" & gstrServerName & ";Port=" & gstrPort & ";Database=" & gStrDBName & ";Username=" & gstrUserName & ";Password=" & gPassword)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmd As New NpgsqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = conn
        cmd.CommandText = _
        "INSERT INTO TBL_REGION(ID,DESC)" & _
        "VALUES(@ID,@DESC)"
        Dim paramID As NpgsqlParameter = New NpgsqlParameter("@ID", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer)
        Dim paramDESC As NpgsqlParameter = New NpgsqlParameter("@DESC", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Char, 100)
        paramID.Value = 1
        paramDESC.Value = "worlds region"

        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramID)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramDESC)
        cmd.Prepare()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

and am getting `ERROR: 42601: syntax error at or near "DESC"`

on

```
 cmd.Prepare()
```

> Database : Postgresql

Comment: DESC is a reserved keyword. Is it really necessary that you name your column "DESC"? Why not something like "DESCRIPT"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DESC` is a reserved keyword in SQL. Use some other name like "`DESCRIPT`" and you should be fine